# Optimize Sparksql queries by scanning once and run many queries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple sql select queries on same dataset, dataset size is around 500GB every single sql query scans data and gives me the output, is there a way to scan data once and run queries on top of it.

below is sample of my code:

```
val DataRDD = sc.textFile("s3n://<Key>:<Key>@mediationprodlogs/vast_track_event/2016/10/3/*")
```

this data spans around 500GB once loaded i am running below Queries:

```
val ClicksPerDeviceid = sqlContext.sql("SELECT DeviceId, count(*) as ClickCount from adreqdata where Network = 9 and EventType = 2 group by DeviceId ")
ClicksPerDeviceid.cache()

val alladreq = sqlContext.sql("select DeviceId,count(EventType) as AllAdreqCount from adreqdata where EventType = 1 and Network = 0 group by DeviceId ")
alladreq.cache()
```

In such format i have many, each query scans all data, is it possible to scan once and give me output. i am aware that sparksql scans only required columns, even if my queries uses same columns can that be done?

Comment: What.... ? Just think about it. If you want to run query on some data d then the query engine will need to scan all the data d. How can you get results without that ?

Comment: @Sarvesh there is cache mechanism, which makes my job run faster but that cant be applied here as my data is huge! in such way i just want to know do we have any other options

Comment: What is the format of the data that you are reading from S3 ?

Comment: its "|^" delimited, i am assigning schema to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Hive query something like this:
(Make sure create a temp table "DevCount")

```
FROM adreqdata
 INSERT INTO DevCount
  SELECT DeviceId, count(*) 
   where Network = 9 and EventType = 2 
    group by DeviceId
 INSERT INTO DevCount
  select DeviceId,count(EventType) as AllAdreqCount 
   where EventType = 1 and Network = 0 
    group by DeviceId
```